# When clicking Button - opening the Email Program in Swift on IOS

Tags: swift

I'm pretty new to Swift and can't seem to find my mistake.

I have created a button and this is my code:

```
@IBAction func sendEmailTest(_ sender: Any) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "mailto:test@gmail.com")! as URL,
        options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

I want to open the mail program with this and I think this should be working.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: looks like your sendEmailTest action is not linked.

Comment: Which part of code isn't working? Can you please check If code gets in function?

Comment: i was always using the "MFMailComposeViewController". Maybe this is better anyways

Comment: Okay somehow my code doesn't even get into my function - even though it's linked

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

```
        import MessageUI


        if !MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            print("Mail services are not available")
            return
        }
        let composeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        composeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

        composeVC.setToRecipients(["test@gmail.com"])
        composeVC.setSubject("Report a Bug or Request a Feature")


        self.parent?.present(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: While using `MFMailComposeViewController` is a fine suggestion, this answer doesn't actually solve the question being asked. If you read the question and the OP's comments, the problem is that the action isn't being called. So this answer does not actually solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You've not put all of your code together there. What you're doing is opening a URL of `mailto:test@gmail.com` which isn't the correct way to do it. You should be using `MFMailComposeViewController`

First and foremost:

`import MessageUI`

And your code should be something similar to:

```
@IBAction func sendEmailTest(_ sender: Any) {

    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
    let composeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    composeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

    composeVC.setToRecipients(["test@gmail.com"])
    composeVC.setSubject("Email Subject")
    composeVC.setMessageBody("", isHTML: false)

    self.present(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {

        print("Cannot send mail")

    }
}
```

Also include a way to handle the code once a user has finished in the mail composer by including after the above method:

```
    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {

    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

You can read more about MFMailComposeViewController on the Apple developer site here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

If indeed, you do want to open a URL, you should implement the following:

```
@IBAction func sendEmailTest(_ sender: Any) {
    if let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "mailto:test@gmail.com") {
        UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL((url as NSURL) as URL)
    }
}
```

Make sure you run it on an actual device, not on simulator.

But MFMailComposeViewController should be the correct way of implementing it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: While using `MFMailComposeViewController` is a fine suggestion, this answer doesn't actually solve the question being asked. If you read the question and the OP's comments, the problem is that the action isn't being called. So this answer does not actually solve the problem.